# Hide/Show for buttons in a table JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this function on my load event, I want the save button to be hidden and show up when I click edit button, currently only the button in the first row isn't visible as I put `x[0].style.display=none`. If I put this line code to `x[1]` and `x[2]` not only the button will not show but the whole line.

How can i fix it with only Javascript?

```
function insert(){

    var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
    var mybody = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    var mytable="";

    for (i=0;i<=2;i++) {

        mytable += "<tr>"

        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].userID + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].firstName + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].lastName + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].dob + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].gender + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + students[i].status + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <button class='del' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='edit' onclick='editRow(this)'>Edit</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='save' onclick='saveRow(this)'>Save</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='cancel' onclick='cancel(this)'>Cancel</button></td>";

        mytable += "</tr>";

        mybody[0].innerHTML = mytable;

        x = document.getElementsByClassName('save');
        x[0].style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName() gives a htmlcollection - you usually have to descend it and not ascend it.

Comment: what do you mean by descend and ascend?

Comment: in your "x" variable you just fetch the elements with class "del". I think that you have also to fetch the save class to assign the display:none property

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to what you are looking to happen. Is the problem that only the first element with the class `del` gets hidden, and you want all the `del` buttons to be hidden? If so, you just need to do `for (var i=0, len=x.length; i < len; i++) { x[i].style.display = 'none'; }`. Or were you looking for this to hide all of the buttons in that cell? Or were you looking to hide the entire row (which wouldn't make much sense to me since you just inserted that row)?

Comment: What I need is to hide only the save button for each row, I've tried your loop, the button is not visible but so is the second line, why? @Travesty3

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS: `.save { display: none; } tr:hover .save { display: inline-block; }`?

Answer (score 2):

## Why did it not work?

You close the loop too late and thus your iteration gets messed up. So the first time it finds one, then two, then three.. Just add all the innerHTML with a single string after the loop.

### Basic solution

To stay as close as possible to your original code (replace students. values back).

```
function insert(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
    var mybody = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    var mytable="";

    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        mytable += "<tr>"
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <span>" + i + "</span></td>";
        mytable += "<td> <button class='del' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='edit' onclick='editRow(this)'>Edit</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='save' onclick='saveRow(this)'>Save</button>";
        mytable += "<button class='cancel' onclick='cancel(this)'>Cancel</button></td>";
        mytable += "</tr>";
    } //We move the closure here.

    //We assing the HTML
    mybody[0].innerHTML = mytable;

    //We get all buttons with the class save and hide them
    x = document.querySelectorAll('button.save');
    for(var i=0, j=x.length; i<j; i++) x[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

## Improvements

Use document.createElement() on document.createDocumentFragement() instead of innerHTML string adding method. Would also make it more easy to assign your later wanted event to show the save button again.

Edit: Thanks to Serlite to improve my english skills, always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want I think ...
I've created a `div` and hid the button like this

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("del");
x[0].style.display = 'none';
```

and created the div to post your `html`

```
document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML  = mytable;
```

Have a look at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jLmacvw/1/) <-- your script in action

Comment: didn't notice the loop issue - I removed the `students` variable.